# Jplayer does not play ogg files in IE

Tags: jplayer, ogg

I have been trying to make ogg files to play in IE10 (they play well in FF and Chrome). I was under the impression that while there is no native support in IE, Jplayer would still play ogg files via the swf. 
However, it doesn't seem to play even with properly pathed swf file.

I tried it in jsfiddle - also doesn't play: http://jsfiddle.net/YAe4g/49/embedded/result/

```
    $("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
    ready: function () {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", { oga: "http://www.makemyradio.com/hooks/mar2013/001.ogg" });
    },
    supplied: "oga"
    });
```

As mp3s don't play in FF, I either need to find a fix for IE/ogg, or must dynamically select from two file formats depending on the browser. Does anyone know if there is a fix foor IE/ogg?

thank you,

Christo

Answer (score 1):

jplayer will play swf files but converts them from *mp3s*, not ogg. You can quickly batch convert an ogg library using the free software Audacity.

You *do* need to dynamically select from two file formats depending on the browser, but jPlayer does this for you. Just install it with both ogg and mp3 (or m4a) and jPlayer will do the rest!

Answer (score 0):

IE doesnot support .ogg file....

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: i can nevr leave a coment so there is no anther way to help the question.. @n1ckolas